# get array of checkboxes checked, and only if seletced in a specific order, then go to URL

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

First time asking here. I tried a number of topics for this, and I currently use a code for checkboxes, but it's for gathering into a mailform and sending to me via php. I can't seem to find exactly what I need for the following scenario.

I am reworking some Flash puzzles to be all html and javascript (or jquery). One puzzle requires the player to enter a code (to open a safe). In Flash they clicked buttons with code symbols on them, so I thought, Checkboxes displayed as images could work...

1. I have 9 checkboxes. Each has a value from 1 to 9. In the layout they are mixed up (they are not positioned on the page in sequential order) and I use images to represent the checkboxes.
2. I want to find out if all the boxes are selected, and if they are selected in the exact order of 1-9.
3. If the checkboxes are checked in the correct order according to their value (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) then on clicking the Submit button, the player is taken to the next webpage.

I can also do this with names or Ids, whatever works. Or php. I was hoping to keep it simple, because I am not savvy with the javvy. I probably know enough to be dangerous to myself and others :)

Thanks in advance for any help, or links to a topic that could point me in the right direction.

Here's my html code.

```
    <form name="checklist" method="post" action="My-Page.php">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="8">
        <img src="btn_8.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="3">
        <img src="btn_3.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="9">
        <img src="btn_9.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2">
        <img src="btn_2.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="5">
        <img src="btn_5.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="4">
        <img src="btn_4.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="7">
        <img src="btn_7.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1">
        <img src="btn_1.png"></label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="6">
        <img src="btn_6.png"></label>
      <input type="submit" value="Open">
    </form>
```

Here's the js I found that gets the values, but I don't know how to make it get the values in that specific order, and then go to a URL, or alert the user to an error.

```
var array = []
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  array.push(checkboxes[i].value)
}
```

- Update. I struggled with this, and finally asked a friend to help. What took me 8 days, he did in like 1 hour, from scratch.
- I do appreciate those who took time to give me some hints, and this site is great for learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't share code , I will not help you fix it. I can give you some hints and you can try to implement that.

1. Call `onClick` function on each checkbox selection.
2. Create an `array` and push the selected checkbox's values into it.

   ```
   // example: checkedArr = [1,2,3,4];
   ```
3. maintain a final order of values with another array

   ```
   // expectedArr = [1,2,3,4];
   ```
4. Deep compare those 2 arrays and depending on their result, proceed with your business logic.
   Comparing two array with their order

   ```
   var is_same_arr = (checkedArr.length == expectedArr.length) && checkedArr.every(function(element, index) {
         return element === expectedArr[index]; 
   });
   ```

Comment: I did include code. Maybe the window isn't expanded on your screen. ANyway, thanks for the hints. I'll try to muddle my way through.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in JavaScript. You maintain a `selected` array that you either add to or remove items from as the checkboxes are clicked. Then, when the form is submitted, you do a couple checks: first you see if all boxes have been checked. Next, you see if all of the numbers in the `selected` array are in order.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
let selected = [];
const numberOfCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#form input").length;

form.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") return;
  if (e.target.checked) {
    selected.push(parseInt(e.target.value));
  } else {
    selected = selected.filter(el => el != e.target.value);
  }
})

function check(e) {
  console.log(selected);
  if (selected.length !== numberOfCheckboxes) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You didn't select all the boxes");
  }
  const inOrder = selected.every((el, i, arr) => i === 0 || el === arr[i-1] + 1);
  if (!inOrder) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Wrong order!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return check(event)">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" /> 3
  </label>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I;ll give this a try.